# AuditAware with Kotlin Exposed

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have a project using Kotlin in Spring Boot.  The tables have the standard audit fields 'createdBy', 'createdDt'.  Is there a way to handle setting these fields in some way that doesn't involve passing these fields around?  Ideally I'd like to intercept every transaction before commit and just set the fields on the entities.

Using JPA and Hibernate, an AuditAware bean could be used to pass the current Principal along with using annotations.  Is there a similar integration available or easily implemented?  I've looked at the EntityHooks class and don't see an easy way to change data.